# Trying to save document directly to server

Tags: save

How would you go about saving a document that is using a program (say Word) that is not on the server, onto the server?  Is there a way to grant access to a folder that is on the server, when saving using a program that is  not on the server.  It is all being done by the same company so we would have all the rights to access the server.  Is there a way to grant read/write access to a folder on the server without having to sign in each time? (Sorry for asking the question 3 times....just trying to be clear).

Thank you,

Comment: What kind of server? A web server? A file server?

Comment: Since it's a web server, you could enable WebDAV on the server and then map it as a network drive on Windows clients.

Answer (score -3):

You can try to use Dropbox or a dropbox-like application, and than use it's API to program everything you need.

Comment: Apologies...yes a web server.

Comment: Interesting idea with the dropbox API.  We are currently logging onto the web server via RDP.